# Suddenly some of my keys stopped working (g, h, the upper arrow)

Tags: updates, keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-keyring, dell-vostro

So today I got a notification about system update. After updating Everything worked fine I worked on it whole day and I did my works 10 min earlier and after 10 min some of the keys (g, h, upper arrow key) stopped working my laptop is only one months old so I don't think there may be issue in hardware can anyone suggest
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you boot into a live session from Ubuntu installation media ("Try Ubuntu") and tell us if the problem persists even when you're not using your installed system?

Comment: Actually I have pre installed ubuntu. Today I try some times keys works but most of the time not working

Comment: Now many keys are not working caps lock light is also not enabled should I call service support

Answer (score 0):

test the keys in  a live session it could be a hardware issue
[Live-session](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started)